# Gurobi and Python: how to query a dictionary using optimal variable solutions

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, gurobi

I'm using Python and Gurobi and I'm having difficulty on how to optimal variable solutions to query a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {(i, j) : func(Z) for i in I for j in J}
```

my_dict results to be like this:

```
{(15687, 'B'): [[7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 7, 0, 0], [0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 0, 0, 7]],
  ...
 (18906, 'C'): [[4, 0, 0, 3], [3, 0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Moreover I have a binary variable x[i, j, z] and an assignment constraint:

```
assignment = m.addConstrs((quicksum(x[i, j, z] 
                                   for z in range(len(my_dict[i, j]))) == 1 
                                   for i in I for j in J), "assignment")
```

Supposing I obtain as optimal solution variables

```
x[15687,'B',0] 1.000000
x[18906,'C',2] 1.000000
```

Is there a way to retrieve the sublist of my_dict corresponding to the "z" index?
(For instance, if my solution is `x[18906,'C',2] 1.000000`  then z = 2 and I want to obtain the sublist `[4, 0, 0, 0]`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not really a nice minimal example to work with, so it's hard to post valid code.

The general problem does not look that tough.

If your original dict looks like:

```
{(15687, 'B'): [[7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 7, 0, 0], [0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 0, 0, 7]],
  ...
 (18906, 'C'): [[4, 0, 0, 3], [3, 0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0]}
```

and your solution is `my_dict_opt`, probably something like this should do (python3):

```
import numpy as np   # easy fp-math comparison

sublists = []
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    n_vars = len(val)  # my assumption
    for i in range(n_vars):
        if np.isclose(my_dict_opt[key + tuple([i])].X, 1.0):  # depends on your dict if .X is needed
            sublists.append(my_dict[key][i])
```

Because of the dicts, the order of elements in sublists is not defined and this should only be a prototype as it's not really clear to me how those dicts are in use for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if possible I want to avoid using numpy. I'm very new to python and I'm having problem on understanding your solution. Moreover Gurobi doesn't support Python 3 so I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: (1) np is just for save fp-math. You can do it yourself. Non-optimal (but working) version: ```eps=1e-3; if(abs(x-1.0) <= eps)```.  The reason is, that you probably want to treat 0.9999 as 1 and you should never do naive equality-checks on floats. (2) Gurobi supports python 3! (3) Difference between py2 and py3 here is just dict-iteration

Comment: Thank you @sascha but unfortunately your solution doesn't work. I don't know if I've committed some mistakes using it but I get TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Comment: I did not check the code as it's mostly pseudo-code. So you might to work out some basics for yourself. E.g. in this case: ```my_dict_opt[key + tuple([i])]```

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to python and gurobi and you are helping a lot!